# In Android Studio 3.1.3 my Theme Editor does not show previews for any theme I select

Tags: android-studio

[image]

In Android Studio 3.1.3 my Theme Editor does not show previews for any theme I select...please HELP!!!

Answer (score 0):

The most default theme is AppTheme. Select It from there. Preview will come asap
Edit 1: This is android studio bug
update build.gradle(app) with:

`dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.1-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.1-alpha3'
}`
to 
`dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.1-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.1-alpha1'
}`
to 
`

Comment: I TRIED ITS NOT WORKING :)

Comment: click on file then click on invalidate/restart and then again ckick on invalidate and restart, this would fix your problem. If this does not works go to YourProject/app/build.gradle and renam further by going to upcoming link

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily solved by changing **res/values/styles.xml** to

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Save the file and check Preview now.

Comment: changing to that, from what? AFAIK what you wrote is already the default

Comment: change `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">` to `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">` Add **Base** to style parent

Comment: Thanks, I missed that part. Also: weird. Theme.() doesn't add anything to Base.Theme.(). IDE bug, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem before and I solved it by adding the *theme deceleration* to the manifest file :

```
android:theme="@style/Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```